Using CreateMosaicDataset_management and AddRastersToMosaicDataset_management in ArcPy
I have a standalone ArcGIS Enterprise Server 10.8.1. I am also using ArcPy with Python 2.7.18. I want to publish an Image Service to my server by creating a SD file, given a folder of DEM .tif files. But I am encountering errors from arcpy.GetMessages(). I think I am using the wrong parameters for arcpy.CreateMosaicDataset_management and arcpy.AddRastersToMosaicDataset_management. Can you take a look and provide any tips?
My ArcPy script has access to my disk. Also those DEM files are not corrupted since they are openable in ArcGIS Pro and shows the grayscale depth correctly.
Here is the stats of each DEM file when I looked at its Properties in ArcGIS Pro:

1 unit of longitude wide and 1 unit of latitude tall (top 50.000056, bottom 48.999944, left 119.999944, right 121.000056)
Around 300 MB when uncompressed
Pixel depth: 32 Bit and Pixel Type: floating point
Number of Bands: 1
WGS 1984 (which is the same as SrsLookup['WGS84'] in my code below)
Angular unit: Degree (0.0174532925199433)

Here is my ArcPy code:
# A bunch of import statements

# Image Service
Name = "DEM_ImageService"
Summary = "Image Service from raster TDF DEM .tif files."
Tags = "Image Service, DEM"

# Local paths
inputFolderPath = r".\Input"      # The folder of imput images
workspacePath = r".\Workspace"    # The folder for (mosaic) dataset and geodatabase
stagingFolderPath = r'.\Staging'  # The folder for storing temporary files
outputFolderPath = r'.\Output'    # The folder with resulting .sd file
rootFolderPath = r'.'             # Directly stores the connection file

# Geodatabase (that stores the mosaic dataset)
GDBName = "Geodatabase.gdb"
GDBPath = os.path.join(workspacePath, GDBName)
# Mosaic dataset
MosaicDatasetPath = os.path.join(GDBPath, Name)

...

arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(workspacePath, GDBName)
arcpy.CreateMosaicDataset_management(GDBPath, Name, SrsLookup['WGS84'], 1, "32_BIT_FLOAT", "NONE", "")
arcpy.AddRastersToMosaicDataset_management(MosaicDatasetPath, "Raster Dataset", inputFolderPath)

print(arcpy.GetMessages() + "\n")

# Create SD Draft file. Analyze the SD Draft file. And stage and upload the service.

Here is the error message:

Executing: AddRastersToMosaicDataset
.\Workspace\Geodatabase.gdb\DEM_ImageService "Raster Dataset" .\Input
UPDATE_CELL_SIZES UPDATE_BOUNDARY NO_OVERVIEWS # 0 1500 # # SUBFOLDERS
ALLOW_DUPLICATES NO_PYRAMIDS NO_STATISTICS NO_THUMBNAILS #
NO_FORCE_SPATIAL_REFERENCE NO_STATISTICS #
Start Time: Fri Apr 5 16:07:47 2024
2024-04-05T16:07:48.329: Loading raster datasets
2024-04-05T16:07:48.365: Error: 80042018: Could not build data source.
[.\Input]
2024-04-05T16:07:48.365: Error: 8004203f: Could not open source as a
raster dataset. [.\Input]
2024-04-05T16:07:48.460: Completed crawling 1 data source items. Added
0 mosaic dataset items.
2024-04-05T16:07:48.461: Error: 8004205e: 1 mosaic dataset items could
not be built.
2024-04-05T16:07:48.465: Error: 8004205f: No new mosaic dataset item
was added.
Succeeded at Fri Apr 5 16:07:48 2024 (Elapsed Time: 1.22 seconds)


This solved my problem. Thank you very much!

@SonofaBeach it may be helpful to add as an answer with a bit more info about the problem

Thank you again!

These lines...
# Local paths
inputFolderPath = r".\Input"      # The folder of imput images
workspacePath = r".\Workspace"    # The folder for (mosaic) dataset and geodatabase
stagingFolderPath = r'.\Staging'  # The folder for storing temporary files
outputFolderPath = r'.\Output'    # The folder with resulting .sd file
rootFolderPath = r'.'             # Directly stores the connection file

...assume that each of those files/folders are in the same folder as the script's current working directory (that's what the '.\' means).  I think that is unlikely.
Change each of those values to the full (absolute) path to the files (instead of the relative path) and that problem should go away.
If that resolves the problem and you still want to use relative paths, then you will need to spend some time figuring out what the correct relative paths would be.  (If you wish to do this, and need help with it, you can ask a new question for that.)
